# RubyMine randomly disappears from the taskbar in Ubuntu

Tags: rubymine

RubyMine keeps on disappearing from the taskbar in **Ubuntu 10.10**. Who else encountered this problem? found any solutions ? This is really annoying, when you work on 2 or more projects in parallel.

There's a ticket [here](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-50947) already, but they're saying that it's a known Gnome issue: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=575739

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find all the details in [this comment](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-17899#comment=27-169762) and in [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libwnck/+bug/144406).